# Smarty ListIt2 CMS MS Break String / Replace Separator

Tags: smarty, cmsmadesimple

I have a list of tags which are input through a checkbox group in ListIt2. They are displayed with `{$item->tags}`

Currently they are displaying with a comma separator e.g. `tag1,tag2,tag3` but no space.

How can I break this string / replace the comma with blank space so that the output is `tag1 tag2 tag3` rather than the comma?

Tried a few methods but not yet had any success. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try {$item->tags|replace:', ':' '}